# Porting a pywinauto script from Windows to X11/Xlib

Tags: ui-automation, pywinauto

In my organization, I have been using pywinauto to automate some UI procedures that could not be done using the sole command line interface.

In an effort to move away from windows, I am evaluating the effort to port the UI automation script to a Linux environment (our tool has a Linux version, including a similar GUI).

I have had a look at the python-xlib project.  But I have the feeling that it is more a framework to develop native X11 applications rather than perform tests on an existing application (I could not find anything like find_window etc...).

Do you have any advice for an X11 framework to automate UI procedures?

Answer (score 2):

Based on several inputs, I finally came up with the following suggestions:

- use pywinauto which has some beta level of Linux support (this support is based on [pyatspi2](https://github.com/GNOME/pyatspi2)).
- use directly [pyatspi2](https://github.com/GNOME/pyatspi2)  to interact with the widgets if they are exposed. To browse through the exposed widgets of the application you want to automate, you can use [accerciser](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/accerciser).
- finally, many framework exist to use only click + keys + mouse locations and are based on image comparison.  There are many around, I have not yet tested any of them.

Finally, since my script is meant to run in a docker environment in CI, I installed [Xvfb](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml) to run the automation in headless mode, without graphics HW.